# Ignore picture upload error

Tags: php

I am having problem with this coding, the upload works fine just that, if I didn't upload any picture it will echo the error, if I upload just one picture it won't show any error message, now I want to make it if nothing to be uploaded, it won't echo the error message but I wanted to remain the error message just incase something went wrong I know there is problem. Thanks!

```
// Upload begins!!

if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][0] != "")
    {
    $target_path =  "."."/uploads/".$petname."/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];

    copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $target_path);
    $filesize1=$_FILES['ufile']['size'][0];
    }


    if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][1] != "")
    {
    $target_path1 =  "."."/uploads/".$petname."/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];

    copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $target_path1);
    $filesize2=$_FILES['ufile']['size'][1];
    }


    if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][2] != "")
    {
    $target_path2 =  "."."/uploads/".$petname."/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][2];

    copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][2], $target_path2);
    $filesize3=$_FILES['ufile']['size'][2];
    }

// Check for error!!
    if($filesize1 || $filesize2 || $filesize3 != 0) 
    {
    }

// If got error, show message 
    else 
    {
    echo "<div class='error'>ERROR : There seems to be problem uploading the pictures.</div>";
    }
```

Comment: is there any reason to use the "."."/uploads/" not the "../uploads/"

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, will remove it once answer is provided.

Comment: So what would constitute an "error"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solved it myself, bottom here is my solution:-

```
if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][0] != "")
{
$target_path =  "."."/uploads/".$petname."/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];

if (!copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $target_path))
{
    $a = 1; 
}

}

else
{
    $a = 0;
}


if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][1] != "")
{
$target_path1 =  "."."/uploads/".$petname."/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];

if (!copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $target_path1))
{
    $b = 1;
}

}

else
{
    $b = 0;
}


if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][2] != "")
{
$target_path2 =  "."."/uploads/".$petname."/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][2];

if (!copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][2], $target_path2))
{
    $c = 1;
}

}

else
{
    $c = 0;
}

if ($a || $b || $c == 1)
{
    echo "Error! There is problem uploading the pictures.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all those who helped me out, I have been figuring this solution for almost 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  this

```
$upload_errors = array( 
    "No errors.",
    "Larger than upload_max_filesize.", 
    "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.", 
    "Partial upload.", 
    "No file.", 
    "Nothing because 5 doesn't exist",
    "No temporary directory.", 
    "Can't write to disk.", 
    "File upload stopped by extension.", 
);

if($_FILES['ufile']['error']==0) { // 0=No errors
    // process
}
else 
{
    if($_FILES['ufile']['error']!=4) { // 4=Not uploaded
        // Error occured other than error code 4(you don't want to show this)
        echo $upload_errors[$_FILES['ufile']['error']].' !<br />';
    }
}
```

**Reference:** [**PHP Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: I guess I solved it myself, kinda brain twisting though, anyway thanks for your help.