# $_FILES array is not empty upon uploading nothing

Tags: php, file, upload

Here is the form

```
form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
```

I am trying to only run my code when only when `if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){` but for some reason the array is not empty upon submitting no files and only clicking submit.

Here is the rest of the code if that will help, thanks.

```
<html>
```

Image Upload

```
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form> 

    <?php

    include 'connect.php';

    if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){
    echo $_FILES['image']['error'];
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpeg');
        $count = 0;

        foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $name){
        $image_name = $name;
        $tmp = explode('.', $image_name);
        $image_extn = strtolower(end($tmp)); //can only reference file
        $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count];
        $filesize = filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);
        $count = $count +1;

        if(count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) > 5){
            echo "You can upload a maximum of five files.";
            break;
        }

        else if(in_array($image_extn, $allowed) === false){
            echo $name." is not an allowed file type<p></p>";
        }

        else if($filesize > 1024*1024*0.3){
            echo $name." is too big, can be a maximum of 3MB";
        }

        else{

            $image_path = 'images/' . substr(md5($name), 0, 10) . '.' . $image_extn;


            move_uploaded_file($image_temp, $image_path);

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('', '$image_name', '$image_path')") or die(mysql_error());

            $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
            $image_link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id = $lastid");
            $image_link = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_link);
            $image_link = $image_link['image'];
            echo "Image uploaded.<p></p> Your image: <p></p><a href = $image_link>$image_path</a>";
            }

        }
        }

    else{
            echo "Please select an image.";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: I don't think it will ever be empty because it holds all the data for the upload.  For example, it will tell you that the file size is `0`. It will be a string of some sort - use `print_r($_FILES)` to check the array and see what you want to use to check if an image is not uploaded.

Comment: Try doing var_dump($_FILES) and viewing the contents...

Comment: What do you mean `array is not empty` ?? It should not be empty

Comment: Is this file named index.php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `is_uploaded_file` PHP function instead:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
  //code here
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: This worked when I put it under `if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){` and used it as `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count])) {`.

Comment: Well, there are a thousand of other different things you could to as well, but this does not mean that it is actually the right way to do nor that you understand what you do. You need to check for the error code, see as well: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php - this become especially important with the `$count` you use here, because, well, you should better know with which kind of data you're working. See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php (uploading array of files)

Comment: This way worked fine. The only problem with I was having with the original code was when I submitted a blank form this code: ` else if(in_array($image_extn, $allowed) === false){
            echo $name." is not an allowed file type<p></p>";
        }` would still run.

Comment: Yes, sure. It works until it breaks. Question is if you're able to actually understand why something works and why not. I can only try to help you in the understanding. I added an answer that shows you *what* is actually going on, maybe it helps you to clarify things: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12538983/367456

Comment: I think @user1672267 knows why it wasn't working - the problem they were having was the validation of an array which will never be empty.  As for the errors, this is easily found via the http://php.net documentation which I'm sure they can look through themselves.

Comment: I do understand what happened now. I was only checking `if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){` to make sure the rest of the code involving the '$_FILES['image']' array was set otherwise an empty submitted form would return an array which would make this `if(in_array($image_extn, $allowed) === false){` execute.

Comment: @user1672267: yes, that's the point. At the moment an array contains more than 0 elements, it is not empty any longer.

Answer (score 19):

This is how `$_FILES` array looks like when nothing uploaded

```
Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )
```

So it's never empty.

The error code 4 `[error] => 4` indicates no file was uploaded and error `code 0` indicates no error and file was uploaded so you can check

```
if($_FILES['image']['error']==0) {
    // file uploaded, process code here
}
```

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292394/ignore-picture-upload-error/12292530#12292530) on SO.

Comment: You can get different errors, I also see `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` (3) next to `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` (4).

Answer (score 4):

You should first of all take a look into the PHP manual because - you're not the first one with that problem - the solution has been written [in there](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` as 0, and `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` as none.

So if you actually want to find out if any file for the `image` element has has been submitted, check for it:

```
 $noFile = $_FILES['image']['size'][0] === 0 
           && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0] === '';
```

Yes, that simple it is.

The test you used:

```
empty($_FILE);
```

will only tell you if the whole form has been submitted or not. So an example in full:

```
$submitted = empty($_FILE);
if ($submitted) {
    $noFile    = $_FILES['image']['size'][0] === 0 
                 && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0] === '';
    if ($noFile) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You save a few bytes by using `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))` resulting in a faster page load.. lol.

Comment: Sidenote: There might not be an error but the filesize is 0 bytes. That's a replay of the upload form w/o actually uploading any file-data. Can happen with browsers, I've seen it with Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

Check value is not null:

```
in_array(!null,$_FILES['field_name']['name'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // Success code Goes here .. 
}
```

`UPLOAD_ERR_OK` returns value 0 if there is no error, the file was uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return
>   $_FILES['userfile']['size'] as 0, and $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
>   as none.

You get an array entry per "file" upload field, even if the user didn't select a file to upload.

Answer (score 1):

I have confronted this issue with a multiple file input.
What I found to be working for checking if any file has been selected is:

```
<?php
$size_sum = array_sum($_FILES['img']['size']);
if ($size_sum > 0) {
 // at least one file has been uploaded
} else {
 // no file has been uploaded
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][0]) || !empty($_FILES['image']['name'][1]) ||  
!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][2]))
```

or

```
for($1=0;$i<count($_FILES['image']);$i++){
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$i])){
   // do something
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){//do some thing here}
```

Comment: How is this code different from the other 6 answers? What is its goal? Please explain it in your answer.

Comment: i just shared the simple code that can be easily understand. i shared for beginners

Comment: You should add an explanation: how this code should be used?