# PHP not detecting file input value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, mysqli

I'm trying to create a form where a user can insert multiple images. How ever, when the file input is empty, the class function (addImgToNieuws) will still run.

Here's the code:

```
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['description']) ) {
    $response = $mysql->addNieuwsItem(
        $_POST['title'], 
        $_POST['description'],
        $id
    );

    if(!empty($_FILES['images']) && $_FILES['images']['error'] != 4){
        $response = $mysql->addImgToNieuws(
            $_FILES['images']
        );
    }
}
```

The form:

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' />
    <input type='text' name='title' placeholder='Titel' />
    <textarea name='description' placeholder='Descriptie'></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='images[]' multiple />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Plaatsen' />
</form>
```

The class function:

```
function addImgToNieuws($images){
    echo 'Function runs';
}
```

**EDIT: Could it be that it has something to do with the fact that it is posted as an array?**

Comment: What ORM are you using here, or have you made your own somehow? `addNieuwsItem` is not a standard PHP function.

Comment: try double `=`  like this:  `!==`  this will take into account the datatype

Comment: addNieuwsItem and addImgToNieuws are both functions within the 'mysql' class.

Comment: Why are you checking for an error code of `4`? You should only proceed with your upload if the value is `0`.

Comment: @M.Doye - Ends up with the same result -> the functions runs.

Comment: Try `if(!empty($_FILES['images']) && $_FILES['images']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)`

Comment: Thank @jeroen - I merely used the correct PHP constant rather than `(int) 0` ;)

Comment: Oh, hold on... now the problem is that when I DO have an image selected, the query wont run.

Comment: lol - we've missed the obvious I think ... `$_FILES['images']` is gonna be an array since you're doing multiple uploads... you're going to need to loop it `foreach($_FILES['images']['error'] as $iError)` and then check each `$iError === UPLOAD_ERR_OK` ;)

Comment: @CD001 Hello, yeah I was thinking the same. Could you answer the question with a good piece of code I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing multiple file uploads `$_FILES['images']` is going to be an array and you'll need to handle each image upload and error trap accordingly.

However it looks as though your `addImgToNieuws()` method handles the entire `$_FILES['images']` array in one go so rather than calling it multiple times it might be better to just log (or capture/output) any failures.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['images'])) {

    $aErrors = array();
    foreach($_FILES['images'] as $aThisImage) {

        // capture any errors
        // I've put the current $_FILES['images'] array into the errors
        // array so you can check the ['name'], ['tmp_name'] or ['error']
        // for each individually
        if($aThisImage['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
            $aErrors[] = $aThisImage;
        }
    }

    //check the errors
    if($aErrors) {
        // take appropriate action for your app knowing that
        // there has been a problem with *some* images
    }

    //no errors
    else {
        $response = $mysql->addImgToNieuws(
            $_FILES['images']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, however I think the foreach loop should look like this: `foreach($_FILES['images']['error'] as $aThisImage) {
        if($aThisImage !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
            $aErrors[] = $aThisImage;
        }
    }`

Comment: That would only give you the error code for each image upload that failed in the `$aErrors` array - you'd not be able to determine *which* image upload actually failed - but if you're OK with that then yeah.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(!empty($_FILES['images']) && $_FILES['images']['error'] != 4 && $_FILES['images'] != ''){
```

Comment: you can also use the "is_uploaded_file" check of php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: i found this on an other question : "If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return $_FILES['userfile']['size'] as 0, and $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as none." 

Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538718/files-array-is-not-empty-upon-uploading-nothing 

Answer Jimp

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this way:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['description']) ) {
    $response = $mysql->addNieuwsItem(
        $_POST['title'], 
        $_POST['description'],
        $id
    );

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'])){
        $response = $mysql->addImgToNieuws(
            $_FILES['images']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hb/nieuws.php on line 17, so I guess we found the problem... it's an array..